# не работает горячая клавиша

Tags: python

код

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard as key
import time
from interface import *

pos_inp = print(pg.position())
pos = pos_inp

run = True

def clicker():
    while run:
        pg.tripleClick(pos)

def ClickerStop():
    clicker.pop

key.add_hotkey('F5', lambda: clicker())
key.wait('F6')
key.add_hotkey('F6', lambda: ClickerStop())
key.wait('F6')
```

при нажатие на ф6 функция кликер должна остановиться, но она не останавиваеться! помогите пожалуйста я ломаю голову над этим уже целый день!!

Comment: Что делает это выражение clicker.pop?

Comment: И опишите словами что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Кстати что в interface?

Comment: @Александ 1. Это я пытался остановить его 2. при нажатие на кнопку активируеться автокликер. 3. В interface интерфейс программы

Comment: Что делает это выражение clicker.pop?Это выражение должно остановить цикл? каким образом? Реализацию покажите.

Comment: Я вам предоставил код, рабочий пример примерно как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: Если хотите помощи приведите пример кода и ошибку которая получается.

Comment: Если код выше то ещё раз повторяю Что делает это выражение clicker.pop

Comment: @Александр Да это должно удалить функ. и остановить цикл 2. Да но ваш код не работает 3. Все работает но когда нужно выключить оно не выключаеться 4. Обьяснил

Comment: Приведите полный код если хотите помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Использование глобальных переменных - ЗЛО! :-)

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
from threading import Thread

isRunning = True

def clicker_start():
    print("call clicker_start")
    global isRunning
    while isRunning:
        #pyautogui.tripleClick(pyautogui.position())
        print(pyautogui.position())
        time.sleep(0.1)
    

def clicker_stop():
    print("call clicker_stop")
    global isRunning
    isRunning = False

def main():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('F5', Thread(target=clicker_start).start)
    keyboard.wait("F5")
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F6", clicker_stop)
    keyboard.wait("F6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

До

> key.add_hotkey('F6', lambda: ClickerStop())

дело не доходило так как эта фукнция

> clicker

блокировала основной поток.

Немного подумав...

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
from threading import Thread


class AutoClicker(Thread):
    running = True
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def start_clicker(self):
        print("clicker started...")
        while self.running:
            print(pyautogui.position())
            # pyautogui.tripleClick(pyautogui.position())
            time.sleep(0.1)
    def stop_clicker(self):
        print("clicker stoped...")
        self.running = False
    def run(self):
        self.start_clicker()
      
def main():
    auto_clicker = AutoClicker()

    keyboard.add_hotkey('F5', auto_clicker.start)
    keyboard.wait("F5")
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F6", auto_clicker.stop_clicker)
    keyboard.wait("F6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ещё имейте ввиду что пока нажата клавиша будет постоянно вызываться функция

Comment: извините не работает

Comment: Что не работает?

Comment: ваш код не работает

Comment: У меня работает)